# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space: Trying to convert a ~5.7million record data set

Tags: java, dataset, heap-memory

I have a sparse 2D data set with about 6 million records each containing up to about 20 features.
I want to convert this into a non-sparse 2D data set with only zero's and ones, but i keep getting the OutOfMemoryError.

Here's an example of my data set:

```
1: 1723762 2737 2 283
2: 239 220 12 19237 2795
3: 3910 2931 86043 26354 349874 73736 2611 93921 4123830
4: 5
5: 4728 2
...(up to ~6mil)
```

I want to convert it into:

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...(up to ~6mil)
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
...(up to ~6mil)
```

notice that on the first row, there is a 1 at the 2nd column, because it has that feature in the original data set, same at the 5th column on the 4rd row and 2nd column on the 5th row.

I have created a code for this, but it already runs out of memory when I try the following:

```
    File data = new File("dataSet.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(data);

    //check how many rows
    int nRows = 0;
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        in.nextLine();
        nRows++;
    }        

    //initializing the matrix
    in.close();
    in = new Scanner(data);
    int[][] matrix = new int[nRows][nRows];
```

It seems it cannot even handle that large an array? It is crucial that I get a non-sparse matrix. Is there any way around this memory error?

Kind regards,

Comment: 6mil x 6mil == 36 trillion. Even if it's just bits, that's still ~4.5TB of data. You simply don't get an address space anywhere near that large, so you're going to need to figure out a way to "stream" the data through memory. Also, I guess I'm a little confused as to why you absolutely need the non-sparse matrix. Any calculations you perform can be abstracted so that you don't need the physical bits set. And I assume this isn't intended for printing, either :)

Comment: Maybe try not keeping all of your data in cache and look into an external way to persist it

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but it looks like the rows are unsorted. Perhaps it would be sufficient to sort them to get better performance for what you are doing? Would give you log(n) access to any feature with binary search... And if n is limited to 20, that should not be too bad?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to achieve? Maybe you can you consider transforming this into a solution using a platform designed for big data (eg hadoop).

Answer (score 2):

Allocate the array in smaller, more manageable parts, make those parts persistent after you do work on them, and then look them up again as needed. The problem here is you can't sort and process the whole thing into memory at once. You are handling an immense amount of data, and no amount of additional heap space will help you if you want to build a 6Mx6M matrix.